# Solr Data Import Properties - Doesnt exist

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am trying to do a delta import via the DIH in Solr. When I tried to do it I get this in my effort log:

```
INFO: Starting Delta Import
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={clean=false&command=delta-import} status=0 QTime=1 
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SimplePropertiesWriter readIndexerProperties
WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder doDelta
INFO: Starting delta collection.
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Running ModifiedRowKey() for Entity: 84430688679548
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed ModifiedRowKey for Entity: 84430688679548 rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed DeletedRowKey for Entity: 84430688679548 rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed parentDeltaQuery for Entity: 84430688679548
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Running ModifiedRowKey() for Entity: document
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed ModifiedRowKey for Entity: document rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed DeletedRowKey for Entity: document rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed parentDeltaQuery for Entity: document
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder doDelta
INFO: Delta Import completed successfully
```

It doesnt work, but I think it is to do with this error:

```
WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties
```

Apparently this file should be in my solr/conf directory but it isnt in this directory. Is this error stopping the DIH working and how do I go about creating this file. Any clues about why it isnt created by default would be interesting too.

Thank you!

Comment: The file is created by DIH. Does the user running Solr have write permissions on the conf folder?

Comment: On the conf folder I have the user "tomcat_user" with the permissions drwxr-xr-x. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Make folder writable by all. Even if it's just for testing this theory.

Comment: The file is not a part of the standard Solr package and is not created automatically.
To fix this warning, simply created an empty file called “dataimport.properties” in your Solr conf directory, eg. /Solr/collection1/conf/ and make sure has write access to it.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue and the fix is to make the conf directory writable. Or just make the dataimport.properties writable for all.